# FragmentManager instantiate correctly fragments but content fragments is invisible

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've been trying to resolve this issue for some time now. My app uses a slidingPaneLayout to show fragments inside it. My issue is in lower API than 28, after some time loading fragments on the slidingPaneLayout, when instantiate new fragments, their content become partially or fully invisible but the fragment itself works correctly (sounds and timer works even with content invisible), if I go background with the app and comes back the content of the fragment re-appears without any issue. 
I don't know exactly what is the causing the issue, if someone had this problem before and have some indications it would be a great help for me.

For the slidingPaneLayout I use this library: https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

For changing my fragments I use this:

```
fun showFragment(fragment: Fragment, containerId: Int, tag: String) {
    val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    fragmentTransaction.replace(containerId, fragment, tag)
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)
    fragmentTransaction.commit()
}
```

What it should look like:

[image]

What happens when this issue first appears

[image: image first error]

After first issue all fragments load with content invisible (the orange arrow is from the activity view)

[[image: image errors after first error][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yx12V.png)

PS: I corrected nearly all memory leaks with canaryleak on the app

PS: I'm using the last version of Fragments, androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.4

Edit: When i force onStop in my fragment like below:

```
var firstTime = true

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    if(firstTime){
        onStop()
        firstTime = false
   }
}
```

The fragment view appears correctly I don't know why

Comment: You should fill a background of different `TextView`s with color. This way you can see what text is there (maybe white on white), are they drawn at all. Maybe their width = 0.

Comment: I've put the background of the parent layout in red. But still same result, the fragment view doesn't get drawn at all. I've been trying to make the whole app less memory/performance eater but still same problem :(